# How to turn back to local computer accounts on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, login, user-accounts, local

I have made VPN connection configuration on local computer.
After reboot logon screen lost user accounts. Default Administrator account works fine with `Administrator` username with empty password, but i still can't logon to my old `UserName` local account.

But i can login to new accounts with the same names created via user profiles in VPN access settings

I have noticed, that newly created user have `UserName.ComputerName` in their profile folder names, but old one have only `UserName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Type this ("PCNAME" is your computer's name, the one you typed in setup, and "USER" is the username) into the Username box:

PCNAME\USER

That should get you logging on to a local account. How to make this default, I don't know. I sure miss the XP logon screen where there was a list of what you could log on to.

Answer (score 0):

You would use something like .\username or computername\username or username@computername